# WPF Dependency Property not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a custom Dependency Property defined like so:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDependencyProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
"MyCustomProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass));

    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyCustomProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyDependencyProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyDependencyProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Now I try set that property in XAML

```
<controls:TargetCatalogControl MyCustomProperty="Boo" />
```

But the setter in DependencyObject never gets hit! Although it does when I change the property to be a regular property and not a Dep Prop

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this..

```
    public string MyCustomProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (string)GetValue(MyCustomPropertyProperty); 
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(MyCustomPropertyProperty, value); 
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyCustomProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustomProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TargetCatalogControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(MyPropertyChangedHandler));


    public static void MyPropertyChangedHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get instance of current control from sender
        // and property value from e.NewValue

        // Set public property on TaregtCatalogControl, e.g.
        ((TargetCatalogControl)sender).LabelText = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }

    // Example public property of control
    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return label1.Content.ToString(); }
        set { label1.Content = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to work with just  'new UIPropertyMetadata(0)'? I have the same problem. What is the reason for implementing assigning mannually?

Comment: @Den I have the same question. Seems silly to have to create a conventional and dependency property for every item in the control

Comment: @Killnine page 64 contains the explanation (WPF 4.5 Unleashed, just click Look Inside - that chapter is available for free):

http://www.amazon.co.uk/WPF-4-5-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672336979

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, unless you call it manually.  There's a property-changed handler you can add to the DependancyProperty constructor call to be notified of when the property changes.

Call this constructor:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx

With a PropertyMetadata instance created by this constructor:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557327.aspx

EDIT: Also, you are not implementing the dependancy property correctly.  Your `get` and `set` should use `GetValue` and `SetValue` respectively, and you should not have a class member to store the value.  The member name of the DP should also be `{PropertyName}Property`, e.g. `MyCustomPropertyProperty` if the `get`/`set` and property name as registered is `MyCustomProperty`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx for more information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Kieren, in your first link there is no "constructor" to call, it explains about the "DependencyProperty.Register Method" which is what I use. Did you post the wrong link? An in your second link it's about the PropertyChangedCallback, where does this come into solving my problem? My Dep Prop Setter is not getting called, that's the problem i'm having!

Comment: I meant the Register method, not constructor.  The setter should not be called, you are using DPs incorrectly and have to follow the pattern described on the links provided.  WPF will not call your setter, it will use SetValue: you must supply a PropertyMetadata object with a handler which will get called by WPF when it changes your value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using MVVM, and overriding the DataContext of your View ?

If you do, then the event for changing MyCustomProperty will be raised on the **original** DataContext and not on the new ViewModel.