# WPF UserControl DependencyProperty use in XAML or by binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want a universal UserControl where i can set a property either by setting its value in XAML directly or by binding it to some model property.

Just like TextBlock Text property works.

Right now i just have the bare simple UserControl, it has a single DependencyProperty TxT and a TextBlock Text property bound to it. No other code present.

If i set TxT in XAML on main window it wont work, binding works.

If i add PropertyChangedCallback to that DependencyProperty it works also in XAML.

So the question, is it mandatory to have PropertyChangedCallback for each property if i want to be able to set it directly in XAML?

This is not clear to me, most don't mention about it, but it also forces me to adding internal control names to change their value in PropertyChangedCallback.

The code is below.

Can it be done some other way?

MainWindow

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDpBare" xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:WpfAppDpBare.Model" x:Class="WpfAppDpBare.MainWindow"
    Background="CadetBlue"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.DataContext>
    <Model:MainModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <local:UserControlSample TxT="DIRECT TXT" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="125" Width="125" Margin="10,34,659,262"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Direct" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Binding" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <local:UserControlSample DataContext="{Binding UCData}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="125" Width="125" Margin="203,34,466,262"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow:Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfAppDpBare.UserControlSample"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDpBare"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="White">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TxT,FallbackValue=...,TargetNullValue=...}" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>

</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class UserControlSample:UserControl {
    public UserControlSample() {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

    public string TxT {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TxTProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TxTProperty, value); }
        }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TxT.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TxTProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TxT", typeof(string), typeof(UserControlSample), new PropertyMetadata());

    }
```

Models

```
  public class MainModel:ViewModelBase {

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="UCData" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string UCDataPropertyName = "UCData";

    private UCModel uCModel = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the UCData property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public UCModel UCData {
        get {
            return uCModel;
            }

        set {
            if(uCModel == value) {
                return;
                }

            uCModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(UCDataPropertyName);
            }
        }

    public MainModel() {
        UCData = new UCModel() { TxT = "BINDING TXT" };
        }

    }

public class UCModel:ViewModelBase {

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="TxT" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string TxTPropertyName = "TxT";

    private string _TxT = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the TxT property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string TxT {
        get {
            return _TxT;
            }

        set {
            if(_TxT == value) {
                return;
                }

            _TxT = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(TxTPropertyName);
            }
        }

    }
```

Full bare project https://wetransfer.com/downloads/199f3db5d183e64cf9f20db4225d4c9820180702001102/f4f61b

[image: sample]

As u can see in the project binding works, direct property text not.

I want it all contained in the usercontrol, so i either set usercontrol property value in xaml or bind to it, without another addition in the mainwindow xaml or code.

Comment: mind sharing a [mcve]?

Comment: @ASh It is basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368808/wpf-dependency-property-not-working It is the most simple code u can do, if my description is not enough i can provide a bare project.

Comment: that one is resolved. if yours doesn't work, then smth is different

Comment: Another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835495/wpf-c-sharp-setting-style-with-parameters/50838193#50838193 post I have shows creation of a user custom control with custom dependency properties and how setting in xaml can be done.  The text values can / should also be completely valid through standard binding the model you are trying to bind to... See if that link helps make sense of the steps...

Comment: Show your code, otherwise we can't help you. That said, "is it mandatory to have PropertyChangedCallback for each property if i want to be able to set it directly in XAML?" - no, definitely not. It doesn't matter whether there is such a callback or not.

Comment: @Clemens I have updated post with the code and added link to a full bare project, binding works, direct value not, if i add PropertyChangedCallback it will work, but many says it is not needed.

Comment: Anyone, i thought it is simple? Yet no matter what i do it wont work in both cases, either direct set or binding, depending on code changes, only adding PropertyChangedCallback makes it work for both cases but everyone is telling me it is not needed and i would also prefer not to add PropertyChangedCallback  for every property, the target usercontrol can have many of them. 

I just want to know the proper way.

Comment: @ASh Well u can check the code and bare sample project now, it just wont work is intended, only if i add PropertyChangedCallback.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the TextBlock's `Text` property to the `TxT` property of the UserControl.

Set the Binding's RelativeSource

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TxT,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, ...}" .../>
```

or assign a `x:Name` to the UserControl and use an ElementName Binding.

---

Then, instead of setting the UserControl's DataContext by

```
<local:UserControlSample DataContext="{Binding UCData}" .../>
```

bind its TxT property:

```
<local:UserControlSample TxT="{Binding UCData.TxT}" .../>
```

---

EDIT: In order to bind directly to the properties of the object in its DataContext, as intended with

```
<local:UserControlSample DataContext="{Binding UCData}" .../>
```

you do not need to declare any properties at all in the UserControl. Remove the TxT dependency property declaration, and bind the elements in the UserControl's XAML directly, as you already did:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TxT, ...}"/>
```

Note however that this is not how UserControl usually work. Yours does now depend on a specific view model type, and can't be reused with other view models.

Comment: That is not true, i'm binding Text property to the Txt as u can see in the question code samples and available project files, if i change it like u propose or with ElementName then direct property set will work, but binding will not. It needs to work in both cases.

Comment: @Programista: You are setting the `TxT` dependency property to "DIRECT TXT" but you don't display this value somewhere. The value being displayed is the value of the `TxT` property of the `UCModel`.

Comment: @Programista There are two TxT properties, one in the UserControl, the other in the view model. The problem and solution would be easier to understand if you would use different names for these properties.

Comment: @Clemens It cannot have different name as this is the binding name it need to bind to, so model needs the same name.

Comment: @Clemens I dont want to do TxT="{Binding UCData.TxT}" as if i will have many more properties i want to bind them to a single model object via DataContext, not repeating that code for every property, besides it shoud work with DataContext, everyone says it is simple, but no one have a working solution, even on other similar questions. Well in the sample project binding works via DataContext, it is the direct TxY xaml value that is not working. I want both.

Comment: Then why do you declare a TxT property in the UserControl at all? Remove it, and write your Binding as you already did, without RelativeSource or ElementName. See my edit.

Comment: @Clemens To use it with binding or direct xaml value set, it must work in both cases, the only way to expose internal usercontrol property in xaml is DP, your propositions only makes it work one way or another IT MUST BE BOTH

Comment: That makes no sense. You **either** bind dependency properties of a UserControl to view model properties and bind the elements in its XAML to its own properties by RelativeSource or ElementName, **or** you bind the elements directly to the view model properties in the DataContext. You can't have both. And you don't need both. Having a set of dependency properties is the usual approach. The idea of binding the internal elements directly to a view model is odd, perhaps even bad.

Comment: @Clemens Yes i need both  as i dont want to repeat code, and it can be done i have seen it, i can have many of that usercontrols, dozen, every with dozen properties, some bound but some standalone, just set value and forget if it is needed, i dont want to make binding for every property every time i use one of that controls, hence, datacontext model binding, full model at once and i also dont want a lot of code or create binding model just to set one single text in a standalone use case, and not to mention IT WORKS if i add PropertyChangedCallback but anyone says it is not needed.

Comment: There is a special case where all properties of the view model that you are initially binding to (by e.g. `{Binding TxT, ...}` without RelativeSource or ElementName) have an equally named property in the UserControl. You may then just do `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`. However, then **all** Bindings in the UserControl will use the control as source object. You can't mix that with Bindings to a view model. Any other approach requires a PropertyChangedCallback that overwrites the Bindings in the UserControl's XAML. The whole idea is nonsense.

Comment: @Clemens What is nonsense? Are u telling me i cant bind datacontext to a model and have the ability to set every property on that control manually if i want without a model? And it is NOT VIEWMODEL, it is only model, a class with data, nothing more, i only use mvvm light for convenience.

Comment: As already said: not without PropertyChangedCallbacks. Read my previous comment once again. And whether you call the binding source object a model or a view model doesn't matter. And STOP SHOUTING. THAT'S ANNOYING.